# Getting past alert execution data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

The opendistro alert history is stored in the `.opendistro-alerting-alert-history-<date>` index

Is it possible to get the alert query data/execution result from a past Completed alert?

I’m not able to find the data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all COMPLETED alerts are saved in .`opendistro-alerting-alert-history-<date>` index as you mentioned, [reference](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/settings/#alerting-indices).

Try adding an index pattern and make sure to include system indices: `.opendistro-alerting-alert-history-*`

You can always view them in ElasticSearch by using this query: `http://my-awseome-es:9200/_cat/indices?expand_wildcards=open,hidden`

As the index starts with .(period) it is hidden just like UNIX hidden files/folders.

I have made a grafana dashboard to visualize the alert data: [12875](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12875)

Please have a look, it can provide a reference for Kibana.